# What would be the advantage of using Colburn j factor instead of h (heat transfer coefficient)

Tags: heat-transfer, heat-exchanger, convection

Why do researchers use the Colburn j factor vs. Re when presenting the thermal performances of a heat exchanger?
A graph of the heat transfer coefficient h vs. Re wouldn't be sufficient?
What are the things that j highlights and h doesn't?

Comment: What is included in the Colburn factor? How does it compare to the Nusselt number?

Comment: Did you do a search? https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-significance-of-Colburn-factor-in-heat-transfer-by-convection